# django template import url tags is there a better way?

Tags: django, django-templates

My goal is to list a few links in a page and I was wondering if there's a better way of do this line of code:

```
<a href={% url ''|add:app_name|add:':'|add:model_name|add:post_fix %}> {{ model_name }} </a>
```

This part : **''|add:app_name|add:':'|add:model_name|add:post_fix**

-- If so, what is the flaw in my thinking, is it the URL-name, or doing too much in the template, or something else? Should I do the construction in python code in *view.py*, if so can you show me how you would tackle this problem?

## a_template.html

```
{% for model_name in list_model_names%}
    ....
    <a href={% url ''|add:app_name|add:':'|add:model_name|add:post_fix %}> {{ model_name }} </a>
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

## url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^stone/$, view.....as_view(), name='stone_index'),
url(r'^cloud/$', view.....as_view(), name='cloud_index'),
]
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views import View
from app.models import (Stone, Cloud)
class ThisView(View):
   template_name = 'app/a_template.html'
   models = [Stone, Cloud]
   model_names = [model._meta.model_name for model in models]
   app_name = 'app'
   post_fix = '_index'

   dict_to_template = {'app_name': app_name,
                    'list_model_name': model_names,
                    'post_fix': post_fix}

   def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return render_to_response(self.template_name, self.dict_to_template)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `render_to_response` is obsolete. Use `render` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be tidier to reverse the urls in the template

```
from django.urls import reverse . # Django 1.9+
# from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse # Django < 1.9

model_names = [model._meta.model_name for model in models]
app_name = 'app'
post_fix = '_index'
urls = [reverse('%s:%s%s' % (app_name, model, post_fix)) for model in model_names
```

Then zip the model names and urls together and include them in the template context:

```
models_and_urls = zip(model_names, urls)
dict_to_template = {'models_and_urls: models_and_urls}
```

You can then loop through the model names and urls in your template.

```
{% for model_name, url in models_and_urls %}
    ....
    <a href="{{ url }}"> {{ model_name }} </a>
    ....
{% endfor %}
```